# detect click on <a> in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a balise "a" inside a div block, and I want to detect the click event when the user click on the button represented by the balise `<a>`.  this is my code:

```
<div class="top-bar-left">
<ul class="menu BreadCrumbs">
<li>
  <a href = "link" class="button" data-clicklistener /> 
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

to detect the click event on   `<a href = "link" class="button" data-clicklistener />` I have tired this code JS:

```
$(".top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs > a.button").on('click', function () {

      var confirmationDialog = confirm("Are you sur ?");
});
```

but this code doesn't work.

Comment: That is not how you create an anchor in `HTML`. Now you will not be able to even   see any link. It should be `<a href = "link" class="button" data-clicklistener>Link</a> `

Comment: Change your selector to `.top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs a.button` because the anchor isn't direct child of `.menu`

Comment: _"I have a balise inside a div block'_ You have a what now?

Comment: @j08691 *A balise /bəˈliːz/ is an electronic beacon or transponder placed between the rails of a railway as part of an automatic train protection system*. - [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balise). Must be HTML6.

Comment: French for tag apparently

Comment: This comment thread is killing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should prevent the default action of the anchor using `event.preventDefaul()`. The main problem here is that you are trying to select the direct descendant anchor of the `.menu.BreadCrumbs` which does not exist. Your code should look something like this:

```js
$(".top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs >  li > a.button").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  confirm("Are you sure ?");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bar-left">
  <ul class="menu BreadCrumbs">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="button" data-clicklistener>Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, according to [Jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), it `Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".` Note that it selects only the direct children,

Comment: yeah, my intention was just to provide the api reference which you had missed. It increases the sureness of your statement,

Comment: Ok. Sure thing. I'm glad we all are trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. Using the `>` operator means it has to the the next child, Not any child.

```
$(".top-bar-left .menu.BreadCrumbs a.button").on('click', function () {

      var confirmationDialog = confirm("Are you sur ?");
});
```

or

```
$(".top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs > li > a.button").on('click', function () {

      var confirmationDialog = confirm("Are you sur ?");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
$("a.button").on('click', function (e) {

      var confirmationDialog = confirm("Are you sure ?");
      if(!confirmationDialog){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Clicked no :(");
      }else{
      console.log("Clicked yes :)");
      }
      
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bar-left">
<ul class="menu BreadCrumbs">
<li>
  <a href = "link" class="button"> Link</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('.top-bar-left').on('click', '.button', function () {
    var confirmationDialog = confirm("Are you sur ?");
});
```

Comment: based on the specificity OP has in his/her selector, I'm guessing this would be too generic

Comment: Or OP doesn't know about the event-delegation approach.

Answer (score 0):

it's because this selector `$(".top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs > a.button")` expects to find the anchor tag as a direct child of `.BreadCrumbs` and it's actually nested under the `li`

instead use

`$(".top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs a.button")` which will look through all children

or to be more explicit you could use

`$(".top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs > li > a.button")`

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(".top-bar-left > .menu.BreadCrumbs > a.button")` to `$(".top-bar-left .menu.BreadCrumbs a.button")`